# In python , while taking input and storing it as an integer value,computer changes the value and stores a different one

Tags: python, integer

Here is my code:

```
n=input()
n=int(n)
print(n)
```

When I give the value 446486416781684178, it prints the same value but stores 446486416781684160. I don't know why.

I attached the screenshot below. I have used an online debugger.

I was using  onlinegdb.com. But the real problem was different.The problem was: The user has to give a number and the code has to find out how many 4's and 7's are there.So my code was:

```
n=input()
n=int(n)
ld=0
while True:
     a=n%10
     if a==4 or a==7:
         ld=ld+1
     n=int(n/10)
     if n==0:
         break
print(ld)
```

It worked perfectly for many random values.But when I entered this number:446486416781684178,the answer should be 7 as there is total seven 4's and 7's.Instead it gave me 6.So I used that online debugger to find out my problem.Then I realized that it was storing 446486416781684160 as I mentioned before.So the answer was 6 as it was calculating 446486416781684160 instead of 446486416781684178

[image]

Comment: This is almost certainly a problem with the online debugger. The Python int may well be going through a JavaScript number (effectively, a float) on the way to display, thus losing precision. Can you point us to the system you're using? This may not even be Python, but rather a JavaScript based Python lookalike.

Comment: It appears to be onlinegdb.com, and it does appear to be a real CPython sitting behind the prompt (running on Ubuntu). My bet is on conversions through JavaScript in the "local variables" display.

Comment: I have edited my problem.Please recheck it.

Comment: Your new question is a duplicate of many others. Quick fix: replace `int(n/10)` with `n//10`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I've managed to reproduce the problem using Python 3.8 on the command line, so this has nothing to do with the online debugger.

Comment: @DavidZ: The OP made significant changes to their question since I commented. They're now asking a different question.

Comment: Thank you very much @MarkDickinson.It solved my problem.Again thanks.

Comment: @MarkDickinson OK, if your earlier comments no longer apply to the current version of the question, how about deleting them?

Comment: @DavidZ: They still do apply to the posted screenshot, where what's shown in the local variables display doesn't match what's shown in the pdb prompt. And that still seems likely to be a problem with the online debugger.